# Python Google API is not returning results

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

I am using python 3.5 and I am try to run google cloud natural language api on python.
I tried this code:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
lang_service = discovery.build('language', 'v1beta1', developerKey= 'mykey')
body = {
        'document': {
            'type': 'PLAIN_TEXT',
            'content': 'Google Inc Apple Inc',
        },
        'features': {
            'extract_syntax': True,
        },
        'encodingType': encoding,
    }
ret = lang_service.documents().annotateText(body=body).execute()
print (ret)
```

mykey was replaced by my api key.
The code worked without errors but I didnt give me any result.

Btw if you know how to run google natural language api on python please help me!